# Prove that the function is defined positively

Tags: calculus

Problem from the textbook:

Assume that $x,y\in(0,1)$ and $n$ is integer and $n>1$, then it is needed to show that the following expression is positive $$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x(1+x)^n}-\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{y(1+y)^n}$$
when $x<y$. 
What is the shortest way to prove this statement?

Comment: And for what stands $n$ here?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $n$ is integer and $n>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove:
$$\left[\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x(1+x)^n}\right]-\left[\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y(1+y)^n}\right]>0
$$
Consider the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t(1+t)^n}$. Note that:
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t)=n;\\
f(t)=\frac1t-\left[\frac1t-\frac1{1+t}-\frac1{(1+t)^2}-\cdots -\frac1{(1+t)^n}\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{(1+t)^k};\\
f'(t)=-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac1{(1+t)^k}<0, t\in (0,1).$$
Hence, the function $f(t)$ is decreasing for $t\in (0,1)$, which implies $x<y \Rightarrow f(x)>f(y)$.

Comment: Please see my comment on the previews answer. Thank you.

Comment: where you get the following expression $$[\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{1+t}-\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}-...-\frac{1}{(1+t)^n}].$$

Comment: It is partial fraction decomposition. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fraction+1%2F(x(1%2Bx)%5E4)).

Comment: Sorry, but that link doesn't work.

Comment: Just a remark: $$f'(t)=-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{k}{(1+t)^k}$$

Comment: Good remark, it is $f'(t)=-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{k-1}{(1+t)^k}$

Comment: And the last comment: Does it important that $\lim f(t)=n$?

Comment: not really, it is useful to find the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $f(z) = z^{-1} -[z(1+z)^n]^{-1}$. That expression is $f(x) - f(y)$. So you're trying to show that $f(x) - f(y) > 0$ whenever $x < y$. What does that imply about $f$? Can you prove that $f$ has this property?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Prove: $$f'(z)=\frac{1-(1+z)^n}{z^2(1+z)^n}+\frac{n}{(1+z)^{n+1}z}.$$ By doing simple algebra yields: $$f'(z)=\frac{(1+z)-(1+z)^{n+1}+nz}{z^2(1+z)^{n+1}}.$$ The sign of the $f'(z)$ depends on the sign of $(1+z)-(1+z)^{n+1}+nz$. Using Binomial Theorem, it can be easily seen, that $(1+z)-(1+z)^{n+1}+nz<0$, since $(1+z)^{n+1}=1+(n+1)z+...$.Since $f'(z)<0$, therefore the function is monoton decreasing, therefore if $z<z*$, then $f(z)>f(z*)$.